# Цвет фигур в Swi-Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Пишу программу с окном и созданием Квадрата и Элипса

```
:- use_module(library(pce)).
start:-new(DW,dialog('Окно моей программы')),new(Picture,picture), send(Picture,width(350)), send(Picture, height(350)), send_list(DW, append, [Picture, new(Width, int_item(width, low:=10, high:=300, default:=150)), new(Height, int_item(height, low:=10, high:=300, default:=150))]), send(DW, append, new(X, int_item(x_coord, default:=10))), send(DW, append, new(Y,int_item(y_coord, default:=10))),send_list(DW,append,[button('нарисовать прямоугольник', message(@prolog, mybox, Picture, Width?selection, Height?selection, X?selection,Y?selection)), button('нарисовать эллипс', message(@prolog, myellipse, Picture, Width?selection, Height?selection, X?selection, Y?selection)), button('стереть',message(Picture, clear))]), send(DW, append, button(exit, and(message(DW, destroy), message(Picture, destroy)))), send(Picture, open), send(DW, open).


mybox(Picture,Width,Height,X,Y):-send(Picture, display, new(_,box(Width,Height)),point(X,Y)),send(Picture,colour,colour(red)).
myellipse(Picture,Width,Height,X,Y):-send(Picture, display, new(_,ellipse(Width,Height)),point(X,Y)).
```

Пробовал: 
send(Picture,colour,colour(red))
send(Picture,fill_pattern,colour(red))
Не работают.

**Вопрос**: Как поменять цвет фигуры (границы) и фон фигуры?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mybox(Picture,Width,Height,X,Y):-
send(Picture, display,new(Box,box(Width,Height)),point(X,Y)),
send(Box, colour, colour(green)),send(Box,fill_pattern, colour(yellow)).